# Auto fill Range from Different Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the standard autofill based on range of column A formula:

```
  Range("G2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
```

I also have this formula to set the range of something:

```
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long

 Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
 With sh
    LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 End With
```

My question is; I am on sheet 2 and need to autofill column G in sheet 2 based off of visible cells in column A on sheet 1

What would my formula look like to do this. I believe I would have to combine some sort of the two chunks of code I have here I’m just not sure how to do it.

Comment: How do you autofill cells on another sheet? Can you provide some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: I'm not trying to autofill cells on another sheet. I'm trying to autofill cells on one sheet based on the range of visible cells in column A on a different sheet

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful. Are you autofilling formulas or values?

Comment: I am dropping a formula down. On Sheet 2: G2=a vlookup formula. On Sheet 1: Column A has a number 1 or 2 that is assigned. On sheet 1 I filter coulmn A to only show data with the number "1". These visible cells vary each week. Back on sheet 2, I need to auto-fill the formula down to the row # of the last visible cell on sheet 1 column A. Does this info help?

Comment: Why not count the number of 1s in sheet 1 and use that?

Comment: I wouldn't oppose that. If the formula can count the varying number of #1 from sheet each week and autofill it down by that many rows on sheet 2

Comment: It's just a COUNTIF formula.